# htaccess use flag N for next condition

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Some searchengines have listed urls in their index with two errors in it. I want to redirect them to the correct location. My problem is, I want to combine two RewriteRules, so it comes only to one single redirect-request.

The misspelled Request-path looks like this:

. /**subdir/** page.php?id=0 **& amp;** name=text

I've marked the problem with bold formating. At first I want to Rewrite the & amp; to the single char & and in the second step, I want to rewrite the subdir to the root directory.

I've this rules in my htacces:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s(.*?)\&amp\;([^\s]*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1&%2 [N,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^feeds/print.php(.*) /print.php$1 [L,NC,R=301]
```

The second condition for the subdir is working fine already, but the first one makes problems! I want to use the N-Flag to use the replaced request for the next condition. It seems that the server is running into an infinite looping or something similar. If I use L in replace for N its working, but makes two redirects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need `N` since you're doing full redirect using `R` flag. 2nd rule will be executed anyway after first one removes `&amp;`.

Also your regex needs some tweaks. Try this code:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.*?)&amp;(\S*)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1&%2 [L,NE,R=302]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^feeds/print\.php(.*)$ /print.php$1 [L,NC,R=301]
```

Comment: Okay, thanks for the tweaks, but there are already two redirects. Is it not possible to combine them to one single redirect? That's the way I understand the N-Flag. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_n

Comment: Ah, now i understand your first sentence in your answer. Yeah, Copy-Paste-Error. I removed the R-Flag in my htaccess then using the N-Flag.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I copied the source i'm using at the moment ([L,NE,R]), but I want to use N. I've edited the source in my question. sorry!

Comment: But 2nd rule won't execute if request is not `feeds/print.php` and your URL continue to show `&amp;` in browser. I think it is better you clarify with examples what redirect/rewrite you are attempting. `N` is almost never needed in my experience.

Comment: Maybe you're right and it's better to not use the N-Flag. If you trace the request to http://www.spielmannszug-meschede.de/feeds/print.php?type=N&amp;item_id=116 , you'll see there are two redirects until you get the correct page. It would be cool to get the same result with only one single redirect. That's why i experiment with the N-Flag. But maybe you're right. If there's a request only matching the &-RewriteRule, it wouldn't work, because then there is no redirection.

Comment: Yes right and also since both rules are so disjoint, combining them into one is not a very good idea.